# UI test automation using Webdriver & Ruby; was not able to initialise the chrome browser session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, rubygems

Our team create functional tests using Rspec and UI tests using Selenium Webdriver with Ruby.

UI tests get executed as Rake tasks. While running one of the test, browser session was not opening, throwing "Error 500" with message as:

"Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError (session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 79):"

I already updated both chrome and chrome driver version; still I was encountering the same error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By going back and forth, I came across the solutions to similar issue but with different techstack and infra, which were not applicable to the issue I came up with.

So finally I found that there was a gem called "chromedriver-helper", which ([link] https://rubygems.org/gems/chromedriver-helper/versions/1.0.0) got deprecated and it was advised to get rid of this gem, while using another one called "webdrivers".

[link] https://everydayrails.com/2019/04/09/chromedriver-helper-webdrivers.html

[link] https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper

So I removed the deprecated gem while added the new one which was suggested and removed following the folder under home directory:

$HOME/.chromedriver-helper. After these two changes, my team is now able to run the UI tests smoothly